# javascript XML ChildNodes

Tags: javascript, xml, nodes

Hi I am trying to access a node's elements with childNodes.  Here is a sample XML

```
<ROOT xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<node>
 <nodeid>28</nodeid> 
 <account_no xsi:nil="true" /> 
 <address1>15 CANCUN CT</address1> 
 <serial_no>112199543</serial_no> 
 <x_lat>25.95513358000</x_lat> 
 <y_lon>-97.49027147000</y_lon> 
 <alarm>
  <alarmid>Outage</alarmid> 
  <alarmtime>2012-07-30T14:46:29</alarmtime> 
 </alarm>
 <alarm>
  <alarmid>Restore</alarmid> 
  <alarmtime>2012-07-30T14:48:37</alarmtime> 
 </alarm>
 </node>
</ROOT>
```

I'm trying to get the second  childNodes but can't using javascript.  I can however get the nodevalues from the first  by this js code.

```
var alarmId = xmlDocOut.getElementsByTagName('alarmid')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
var alarmTime = xmlDocOut.getElementsByTagName('alarmtime')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

If i try to use ...[i].childNodes[1].nodeValue the js will throw an error saying 'Object Required' on that line.
I've tried

```
...[i].childNodes[1...4].nodeValue
```

and

```
...[i].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.
```

And still nothing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it, i just had to add an ...[i+1].childNodes[0].nodeValue to the subscript to get the second alarm elements.

Answer (score 0):

xmlDocOut.getElementsByTagName('alarmid')[i].childNodes[1] doesn't exist; every alarmId node only has 1 child node; a text node.

for example:

```
<alarmid>Outage</alarmid>
```

has 1 childNode; a textNode with text == "Outage".